# Foreach for records listing but half row content in different order

Tags: php, codeigniter, syntax, matching

I am Developing Matching for Students to learn language.

have a look :

[image: At present it looks like :]

There is no error in this code. In this, i am looping all content from database perfectly. But when looping content from database i want to show Images randomly. If first image is from 1st record then it will be shown on other row. ( ramdomly ). Or If second image is from 2nd record then it will be shown on other record. ( not on same ).

Now, i want to show the right side options randomly. Don't know about the query for left and right side so that right side content is different. ( Image ). At present, it is showing same picture with right option.

I need to show random images which is not same as answer. After that user is adding answer to text box before the image.

```
if(!empty($question)){ // empty start
           $options = $this->general_db_model->getAll('re_matching_options','ID',array('MatchingID'=>$question->ID));
           ?>
                    <div class="quiz_section">
                        <h4 class="no-margin-top"><?php echo $question->Question?></h4>
                        <ul class="quiz_list list-unstyled">
                        <?php if(!empty($options)){ foreach($options as $option){
            $countoption++;
            ?>
                          <li class="row"> <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6"> <span class="box_question"> <span class="question"><?php echo $countoption?>.</span> <span class="question">
                            <?php echo $option->FirstCol?> / <?php echo $option->FirstCol2?>
                            </span> </span> </span> <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 text-center"> <span class="answers_box">
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $option->ID?>" name="matching_<?php echo $question->ID?>_<?php echo $option->ID?>_<?php echo $countoption?>"/>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="" name="matching_ans_<?php echo $question->ID?>_<?php echo $option->ID?>"/>
                            <span class="test"><?php //echo $option->Answer
                              echo '<a href="'.base_url().'uploads/banner/'.$option->Answer.'" target="_blank"><img src="'.base_url().'uploads/files/'.$option->Answer.'" style="width:62px;"></a></span> </span> </span> </li>'; ?>
                          <?php } }?>
                        </ul>
                      </div>                                                            
                    <?php
        }//empty end
```

HTML :

```
<div class="quiz_section">
                        <h4 class="no-margin-top">Heading of Question for Text to Image</h4>
                        <ul class="quiz_list list-unstyled">
                                                      <li class="row"> <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6"> <span class="box_question"> <span class="question">1.</span> <span class="question">
                            asdfdsfdsf / ddddddd                                </span> </span> </span> <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 text-center"> <span class="answers_box">
                            <input type="hidden" name="matching_93_46_1" value="46">
                            <input type="text" name="matching_ans_93_46" placeholder="">
                            <span class="test"><a target="_blank" href="http://localhost/burmese/uploads/banner/Melon-Daiquiri.jpg1_2_1.jpg"><img style="width:62px;" src="http://localhost/burmese/uploads/files/Melon-Daiquiri.jpg1_2_1.jpg"></a></span> </span> </span> </li>                                                            <li class="row"> <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6"> <span class="box_question"> <span class="question">2.</span> <span class="question">
                            deepak / deepak                                </span> </span> </span> <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 text-center"> <span class="answers_box">
                            <input type="hidden" name="matching_93_47_2" value="47">
                            <input type="text" name="matching_ans_93_47" placeholder="">
                            <span class="test"><a target="_blank" href="http://localhost/burmese/uploads/banner/banner1.png"><img style="width:62px;" src="http://localhost/burmese/uploads/files/banner1.png"></a></span> </span> </span> </li>                                                            <li class="row"> <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6"> <span class="box_question"> <span class="question">3.</span> <span class="question">
                            New row added / ddddddd                                </span> </span> </span> <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 text-center"> <span class="answers_box">
                            <input type="hidden" name="matching_93_55_3" value="55">
                            <input type="text" name="matching_ans_93_55" placeholder="">
                            <span class="test"><a target="_blank" href="http://localhost/burmese/uploads/banner/images.jpg"><img style="width:62px;" src="http://localhost/burmese/uploads/files/images.jpg"></a></span> </span> </span> </li>                                                          </ul>
                      </div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: can post your html for the above structure

Comment: @saurabhkamble, Please check, i just updated my question with HTML structure. 

i think this can be possible only with the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **There is no any logical issue. just an problem with `'` close position**

---

**In your last line**

```
                echo '<a href="'.base_url().'uploads/banner/'.$option->Answer.'" target="_blank">
                        <img src="'.base_url().'uploads/files/'.$option->Answer.'" style="width:62px;">
                        </a></span> </span> </span> </li>'; ?>
                            ^^                         ^^
```

**This line should be move out like this**

```
echo '<a href="'.base_url().'uploads/banner/'.$option->Answer.'" target="_blank">
    <img src="'.base_url().'uploads/files/'.$option->Answer.'" style="width:62px;">
    </a>'; ?>
</span></span></span></li>
```

---

**so Final well-form code is**

```
if(!empty($question)){ // empty start
    $options = $this->general_db_model->getAll('re_matching_options','ID',array('MatchingID'=>$question->ID));
?>
<div class="quiz_section">
    <h4 class="no-margin-top"><?php echo $question->Question?></h4>
    <ul class="quiz_list list-unstyled">
    <?php if(!empty($options))
    { 
        foreach($options as $option)
        {
            $countoption++;
            ?>
            <li class="row"> 
                <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6"> 
                    <span class="box_question"> 
                        <span class="question">
                            <?php echo $countoption?>.
                        </span> 
                        <span class="question">
                            <?php echo $option->FirstCol?> / <?php echo $option->FirstCol2?>
                        </span> 
                    </span> 
                </span> 
                <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 text-center"> 
                    <span class="answers_box">
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $option->ID?>" name="matching_<?php echo $question->ID?>_<?php echo $option->ID?>_<?php echo $countoption?>"/>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="" name="matching_ans_<?php echo $question->ID?>_<?php echo $option->ID?>"/>
                        <span class="test">
                        <?php 
                            echo '<a href="'.base_url().'uploads/banner/'.$option->Answer.'" target="_blank">
                                    <img src="'.base_url().'uploads/files/'.$option->Answer.'" style="width:62px;">
                                    </a>'; ?>
                        </span> 
                    </span> 
                </span>
            </li>
          <?php 
        } 
    }?>
    </ul>
</div>                                                            
<?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. :)

There is no error in this code. In this, i am looping all content from database perfectly. But when looping content from database i want to show Images randomly. 

If first image is from 1st record then it will be shown on other row. ( ramdomly ). Or If second image is from 2nd record then it will be shown on other record. ( not on same ).